# retrieve google forms edit urls and maintain existing data structure

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-forms

I am interested in making some alterations to a [snippet](https://gist.github.com/pierandrea/3fcccada803ca34c9e09) of the code that allows you to record URLs to edit Google Form's responses.

What I wish to achieve is a repeatable automated process of receiving those URLs upon form submit. **However, one condition that I want to follow is to have those URLs pasted in the first column of the spreadsheet, maintaining the integrity of existing data in the following columns.**

I think it is the only viable option for me, as the form is still in the development stage, and may receive more variables as the time progresses.

I have attempted:

1. Manually inserting a column in the Responses' Google Sheet and then try to setup the `assignEditUrls{}` function, but it yields no results.
2. Using a one time mini-function to insert the left most column, and then run the code. Also produced no results, unless it was included in the main function, which then inserts the leftmost column every time there is a submission.

Here's that:

```
function insertLeftMostColumn(){
  //insert a column before the first one
  sheet.insertColumnBefore(1);

  //rename the header for the new column
  var cell = sheet.getRange("A1"); 
  cell.setValue("columnName");
}
```

This is the function.

```
function assignEditUrls() {
  var form = FormApp.openById('1cg7bGRQjsv91sSCjYCwNJyoB3wN_MZ_9raV3tP3v1MA');
    //enter form ID here

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');

  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn(); // This logs the value of the very last column of this sheet (without the values)


    //Change the sheet name as appropriate
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var urlCol = 5;
  var responses = form.getResponses();
  var timestamps = [], urls = [], resultUrls = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
    timestamps.push(responses[i].getTimestamp().setMilliseconds(0));
    urls.push(responses[i].getEditResponseUrl());
  }
  for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {

    resultUrls.push([data[j][0]?urls[timestamps.indexOf(data[j][0].setMilliseconds(0))]:'']);
  }
  sheet.getRange(2, urlCol, resultUrls.length).setValues(resultUrls);  
}
```

[current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7p1T.jpg)

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jToEJ.jpg)

Comment: Welcome. What is your question? In other words, where do you get stuck?

Comment: Hi, @Rubén! In layman's terms, I want the URLs to be stored in the first column, followed by all other columns. But I can't achieve that in a way that it continues to record the answers automatically upon the google form's submission. Let me know if this makes sense? Thanks.

Comment: You need to use an onFormSubmit installable trigger. For details see [Show URL used to edit responses from a Google Form in a Google Spreadsheet by using a script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/89551/88163)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is right, you want to know how to insert the edit URLs in the first column instead of the last one.

### If so, you need to implement some small modifications in your code:

1. Insert an empty column into the sheet, e.g. with the function `insertLeftMostColumn()`, as you intended above. Keep in mind that if you want to run the function only once, it needs to be called separately from `assignEditUrls()`, so you have to define `sheet` one more time within the function
2. `urlCol` is the column number, where the URLs shall be pasted. To change the column to the first one, modify `var urlCol = 5;` to `var urlCol = 1;`
3. `data[j][0]?urls[timestamps.indexOf(data[j][0]` tries to find timestamps in the first column.

   Given that you inserted an empty column and the timestamps have been shifted to the second column - you need to change the code to `data[j][1]?urls[timestamps.indexOf(data[j][1];`
4. If you want the new URLs to be inserted every time upon form submit, you need to incorporate into your `assignEditUrls()` function a `Form Submit` trigger. [Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) you can find information about how to incorporate installable triggers.

Comment: Thanks for your post, I will attempt it by the end of today and get back to you with my results!

Comment: Glad to hear it!